# Why do console.log() works but not array.push() on async code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I have this code, which is trying to track all the redirects an URL has. The console.log() outputs everything correctly for the single responses, but when I try to output the result of responses.push(), it just print X times the same output.

I am using Node v8.12 and Axios 0.18

```
const axios = require('axios')

const instance = axios.create({
    maxRedirects: 0
})

var HttpResponse = {
    status: '',
    statusText: '',
    location: '',
    headers: {}
}

let url = 'url with redirects here'

const doCall = async function(url){

    return instance.get(url)
    .then((response) => {

        let newresponse = HttpResponse
        newresponse.status = response.status
        newresponse.statusText = response.statusText
        newresponse.headers = response.headers
        return {
            final: true, 
            response: newresponse
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        if( err.response ){

            let newresponse = HttpResponse
            newresponse.status = err.response.status
            newresponse.statusText = err.response.statusText
            newresponse.headers = err.response.headers

            return {
                final: false, 
                response: newresponse
            }

        }else{

            let newresponse = HttpResponse
            return {
                final: true,
                response: newresponse
            }
        }
    })
}

const start = async function(){

    let responses = []
    let result = await doCall(url)
    console.log(result)
    responses.push(result)

    while( result.final != true ){
        result = await doCall(result.response.headers.location)
        console.log(result)
        responses.push(result)
    }

    console.log(responses)
}

start()
```

Output of each console.log but the last one using an URL with a 301 redirect:

```
{final: false, ...}
{final: true, ...}
```

Output of the console.log(responses):

```
[{final: true, ...}
{final: true, ...}]
```

Why is responses.push() not working as expected?

Comment: You keep overwriting `result`, and after the while loop `responses` contains a bunch of references to a single `result`. Use for instance `responses.push(JSON.stringify(result));` instead.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem @ChrisG - he's assigning a new value to result, not changing result object - I dummied up his code ... https://jsfiddle.net/jLparc9k/ ... works as it should - I suspect the code in the question isn't exactly the code with the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right, that's not it.

Comment: @JaromandaX Removed my comment as I didn't see it was about Node.js. So not running in Chrome or anything.

Comment: @ChrisG this is working with JSON.stringify(), thanks

Comment: I am checking it on the command line, not on browser, for all who asked

Comment: Please make sure the code you post here is capable of reproducing the problem. What you have in the question won't run.

Comment: if JSON.stringify fixes the issue, then the code you've posted does not represent the real code you use

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I am sorry, I tried to simplify the code here. I have written now the real code

Comment: still doesn't make sense that you get repeats of the last value in the array though

Comment: `let newresponse = HttpResponse` does **not** construct a *new* response but instead re-uses the same `HttpResponse` object over and over.

Comment: @Bergi then why is console.log() working properly and returning the proper response always?

Comment: @antsanchez Because you always temporarily modify the (single) object, then log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created simple POC of your code to be runnable without special requirements and it works like a charm.

```js
let i=0;

const doCall = async function(url){

    return Promise.resolve()
    .then((response) => {
        if (i > 4) {
            return {final: true};
        }
        return { final: false};
    })
}

const start = async function(){

    let responses = []
    let result = await doCall()
    console.log(result)
    responses.push(result)

    while( result.final != true ){
        result = await doCall()
        console.log(result)
        responses.push(result)
        i++;
    }

    console.log(responses)
}

start();
```

There is probably some other issue than you think, is there more code you can provide? Can you copy the full output of your code? (i.e. run it with `node server.js > output.txt`) and then give us the full output?